# Resource '@xml/provider_paths' not found in androidmanifest.xml:73

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, build, android-manifest

I am upgrading my 2019.1 Unity/Firebase App to 2020.1.3

When attempting to build I get the error: Resource '@xml/provider_paths' not found in androidmanifest.xml:73

/Users/spin/Desktop/Yellows Unity App - Android 2019/Temp/gradleOut/unityLibrary/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:73:13-75:58: AAPT: error: resource xml/provider_paths (aka com.Yellows.Monthly:xml/provider_paths) not found.

Note: I had to update the PlayServicesResolver to play-services-resolver-1.2.157.0.unitypackage. I am using older Firebase from 2019 that I believe needs the Android Support v4. If I comment out the lines below, it builds but Firebase does not work...

These are the lines my manifest:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="com.Yellows.Monthly.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">

<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: Ever resolve this?